# Best way to fetch 1000's of images from phones photos gallery swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uicollectionview

I am trying to create an app which has upload image feature. I want to create a screen which loads all the images, which could be more than 1000 images from photos gallery. And then load all those in Collection view sorted and group by date.

I tried Batch loading but that is not working, it loads only first batch. Is there any other approach to do this? Is there any tutorial I can refer to?

```
 var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var photosDict = Dictionary<String,[Photo]>()
    var photoAssets: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>?
    let itemsPerBatch = 20
    var batchNumber = 0

   func grabPhotos() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let imgManager=PHImageManager.default()

            let requestOptions=PHImageRequestOptions()
            requestOptions.isSynchronous=true
            requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

            let fetchOptions=PHFetchOptions()
            fetchOptions.sortDescriptors=[NSSortDescriptor(key:"creationDate", ascending: false)]

            self.photoAssets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)

            self.loadMorePhotos(imgManager: imgManager, requestOptions: requestOptions)

            self.batchNumber = self.batchNumber + 1
        }
    }


    func loadMorePhotos(imgManager: PHImageManager, requestOptions: PHImageRequestOptions) {
        photosDict.removeAll()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"

        if let photoAssetsUW = self.photoAssets, photoAssetsUW.count > 0 {
            print(photoAssetsUW)
            print(photoAssetsUW.count)
            for i in (self.batchNumber * self.itemsPerBatch)..<(self.itemsPerBatch * (self.batchNumber + 1)) {
                if i < photoAssetsUW.count {
                    let photoAsset = photoAssetsUW.object(at: i)
                    if let creationDate = photoAsset.creationDate {
                        let stringDate = formatter.string(from: creationDate)
                        var imageURL: String = ""
                        photoAsset.requestContentEditingInput(with: PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()) { (eidtingInput, info) in
                            if let input = eidtingInput, let imgURL = input.fullSizeImageURL {
                                imageURL = imgURL.absoluteString
                            }
                        }

                        imgManager.requestImage(for: photoAssetsUW.object(at: i) , targetSize: CGSize(width:500, height: 500),contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { (image, error) in
                            if let imageUW = image {
                                if self.photosDict[stringDate] == nil {
                                    self.photosDict[stringDate] = [Photo(image: imageUW,imagePath: imageURL)]
                                } else {
                                    self.photosDict[stringDate]?.append(Photo(image: imageUW,imagePath: imageURL))
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("You got no photos.")
        }
        print("photosDict count: \(self.photosDict.count) \(self.photosDict)")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let keys = Array(photosDict.keys).sorted(by: <)
        let currentKey = keys[indexPath.section]
        let imageList = photosDict[currentKey]
        if indexPath.row == imageList?.count {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoItemCell

            let requestOptions=PHImageRequestOptions()
            requestOptions.isSynchronous=true
            requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

            loadMorePhotos(imgManager: PHImageManager.default(), requestOptions: requestOptions)
            return cell
        }


        let cell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoItemCell
        cell.img.image = imageList?[indexPath.row].image
        return cell
    }
```

I want to create a screen which looks exactly like Apple Photos app, and loads all images and videos from photos app.

Comment: Follow Apple's [sample app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/browsing_and_modifying_photo_albums?language=objc).

Comment: See if your hole sole purpose is to upload image on server, then instead of showing it in collection view use library by which you can use single and multiple image and upload it on wherever you want. There is an excellent library called 'Fusuma' use that .